# When to Extend PCR

Tags: tpm

The computational meaning behind extending the PCR it is easily found and clearly explained.  Simply, it is extending the hash.  It fact it's so simple that I think everyone forgets to say why it's done and how it's managed, leaving me to make a few assumptions:

Clearly the PCR is for asserting the state of what was measured, and thus the entity doing the measurement should be the owner of the PCR.

- **Assumption 1: Nothing/nobody else should be extending it, as the previous PCR would be lost.**
- **Assumption 2: Whenever the PCR is updated, the list of measurements to perform should also be updated.  Otherwise the measurement hash and PCR would no longer match.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two guidelines to keep in mind for extending PCRs:

- Any time a platform measurement is performed, a hash of that measurement should extend a PCR.
- The locality and core root of trust for measurement (CRTM) used, along with platform rules, determine which PCR should be extended.

The TPM's role as the core root of trust for reporting (CRTR) comes down to being able to sign a quote over a specified set of PCRs. Only measurements that are extended in to PCRs can be covered by the TPM signature. Also, any feature that locks key usage to PCR values can only be affected by measurements which extend PCRs.

Which PCR to extend can be somewhat complicated, and may just require making a decision on your own. The TCG has guidelines for PC clients based on BIOS or EFI. Those guidelines specify that PCRs 0-7 be used for measurements taken by the BIOS/EFI itself (or at least based on the static CRTM) before an OS has been booted. The next 8 PCRs are basically reserved for the "secure OS" which is running on the extended static CRTM. Within that group, the decision about which PCRs are used is up to the OS. Windows and Linux use a different set of PCRs for the measurements. Within Linux, different PCRs may be used by GRUB and IMA.

Take a look at the PCRs used on your platform, and see which ones stay unused, and there's a decent chance you could use one for your own purposes. The TPM specs do reserve a few PCRs for special use or testing. You may want to stay away from these for production use, but you may want to use them for development. (A PCR that can be reset by the user without requiring a reboot is not great for security, but is a really useful feature when developing your use case.)

You are correct that anything that extends a PCR should be logged, though there are situations for which this is arguably not necessary. If you are simply locking something to a given PCR value, you may not care about how that value was achieved--only that it *was*. When performing remote attestation, evaluating the signature that covers the measurements requires being able to replicate the values of PCRs from the measurements, which in turn requires having a log of measurements which preserves order.